# Multitask-Process in C++ with Windows Form and Winsock

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, winsock

I have to write a program which includes communication using TCP/IP and which is controllable through a Windows form.

Therefore I have written a multithreaded program using `pthread.h`.  The one thread is for the Windows form, the other thread is for the Winsock stuff.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1, t2; // declare 2 threads.
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, RunTCPIP, NULL); // create a thread running TCP-Communication
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, RunForms, NULL); // create a thread running Windows Forms
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void * RunForms(void * argument)
{
    //run GUI
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Server_C_GUI::Mainform form;
    Application::Run(%form);
    return 0;
}

void * RunTCPIP(void * argument)
{
    //Winsock-stuff....
    return 0;
}
```

There are some variables which I have to use in both threads. And that's my problem. I have created `globals.h` where I have defined my global variables.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef EXTERN
#define EXTERN extern
#endif

//Variables for OperatingMode & GUI
EXTERN const string szServerResponse;
EXTERN char cPlay;
EXTERN char cBreak;
EXTERN char cQuit;
```

I have included `globals.h` in the main.cpp - there it works. But when I try to include `globals.h` in `MyForm.h` - the header of my CLR Windows form - several failures arise.

In `MyForm.h` I would like, for example, to write the following code:

```
private:
    System::Void btnQuit_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        cQuit = 0; //cQuit = global variable
    }
```

How can I use global variables in a multithreaded program with Winsock and CLR Windows forms? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a) pthreads and the CLR are not compatible, you cannot use both in the same application b) use CLR threading... if and only if you need it.

Comment: Thanks.. I have to admit, that i have no idea about CLR. So what do you suggest? Whats the easiest way to handle this? Would it be possible with mfc forms?

Comment: I would suggest either using MFC or CLR but not mixing the two. Also I would suggest using the framework specific mechanisms that support async calls. You really don't need another thread for winsock. Winsock supports non-blocking operations.

Comment: Usually the GUI thread is the main thread of a program, you don't create a thread for it.  You do create a worker thread for the Winsock stuff, if needed.  But instead of using Winsock, it might be easier to use the great socket library built into .NET.  I'm not sure if it's easier to use this on a separate thread or in a non-blocking way.